# Can't make Boostrap tab taller

Tags: html, css

I have a page:

https://my.kendozone.com/tournaments/fake-tournoi/

I would like to make tabs bigger (like 100 pixel height).

Of course, text should be centered vertically.

I couldn't do it by myself, I will put it in a snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://my.kendozone.com/css/app.css">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,500,700,900">
    <script src="https://my.kendozone.com/js/guest_app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header"><img src="https://my.kendozone.com/images/banners/KZ-04.jpg" class="banner" alt="Kendozone Banner">
</div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-solid nav-justified top-banner-guest">
    <li class="active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab" id="tab1" aria-expanded="true">Datos generales</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#competitors" data-toggle="tab" id="tab2" aria-expanded="false"> Competidores</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#trees" data-toggle="tab" id="tab3" aria-expanded="false">Arboles</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#rules" data-toggle="tab" id="tab4" aria-expanded="false">Reglas</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Don't use Bootstrap if you need customization **and** don't have basic knowledge about HTML and CSS.

Comment: The linked page is giving a 500 error. Is it down permanently?

Answer (score 0):

In your SASS or LESS `_variables` file (you *are* compiling from source, right?) look for the following (around line 360) and adjust as needed:

```
// Basics of a navbar
$navbar-height:                    50px !default;
$navbar-margin-bottom:             $line-height-computed !default;
$navbar-border-radius:             $border-radius-base !default;
$navbar-padding-horizontal:        floor(($grid-gutter-width / 2)) !default;
$navbar-padding-vertical:          (($navbar-height - $line-height-computed) / 2) !default;
$navbar-collapse-max-height:       340px !default;
```

If you are not compiling from source then you will need to generate a custom version: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar

Comment: Nop, I'm not, I guess I'm using a generated CSS Version, but I have o LESS / SASS source

Comment: If you are using a pre-generated version you can still generate a customised version (updated answer).

Comment: I see, I didn't know that.... Shouldn't it be easier just customize CSS properties???

Comment: Sure, you could edit the generated css directly but you may have to find multiple places to make the changes (and make the *correct* changes). The variables provided in either SASS, LESS or the customiser are there for this very reason. I *highly* recommend getting into LESS or SASS - you will never look back. :)

Comment: Ok that s why I couldn t make it... I will definitively check it. Tx

Comment: Is there a way to generate my base SASS file, like in here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#navbar
??? but in SASS?

Comment: No. The customiser is like a shortcut to the sass variables file but always outputs compiled css. If you are using sass you can just edit the variables file directly.